# Crunch sound when hitting the accelerator

Tags: noise, subaru, manual-transmission

I've been experiencing a crunching sound under certain conditions for a few years now and I'm trying to get to the bottom of it. It's a 2014 Subaru BRZ

- Crunch only happens when car is rolling
- Happens in any gear or neutral, clutch up or down
- Only happens at the start of acceleration
- High pitched crunching sound that happens only for an instant
- Sounds like metal hitting metal

Some forums have suggested that it might be the firewall, headers or a misfire (which I doubt) and I'm going to investigate these when I have the chance. Any other suggestions are very much welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!